# How to Convert a byte array into an int array?

Tags: c#, arrays

How to Convert a byte array into an int array? I have a byte array holding 144 items and the ways I have tried are quite inefficient due to my inexperience. I am sorry if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find a good answer anywhere.

Comment: What are the ways you have tried?

Comment: Just to mention - byte is 8 bit, int is 32 bit, and you are converting a byte to int. All of the converted ints will range from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simple:

```
//Where yourBytes is an initialized byte array.
int[] bytesAsInts = yourBytes.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

Make sure you include `System.Linq` with a using declaration:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And if LINQ isn't your thing, you can use this instead:

```
int[] bytesAsInts = Array.ConvertAll(yourBytes, c => (int)c);
```

Comment: I got an error: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1166981: Make sure to reference `System.Linq` in your project. (Which version of the .NET framework are you targeting, by the way?)

Comment: This approach is very slow: Linq is not optimized for `byte` block copies. It's _much_ faster to do `int[] bytesAsInts = new int[ yourBytes.Length / 2 ]; Buffer.BlockCopy( yourBytes, 0, bytesAsInts, 0, yourBytes.Length );`.

Answer (score 13):

I known this is an old post, but if you were looking in the first place to get an array of integers packed in a byte array (and it could be considering your array byte of 144 elements), this is a way to do it:

```
var size = bytes.Count() / sizeof (int);
var ints = new int[size];
for (var index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    ints[index] = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, index * sizeof (int));
}
```

Note: take care of the endianness if needed. (And in most case it will)

Comment: Nice, was looking for this. People seem to forget that (int)byteVar is not the same as converting a bytearray into an int (for example 4 bytes for one int)

Comment: There is a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5896716/238419 That question is about `int[]` to `byte[]` but this solution should work regardless

Answer (score 10):

Use Buffer.BlockCopy instead of Array.ConvertAll.

ref [Converting an int[] to byte[] in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896680/converting-an-int-to-byte-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8 };
int[]  ints= Array.ConvertAll(bytes, Convert.ToInt32);
```

will return  ints[]={0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8},

not  return  ints[]={0x04030201,0x08070605}

should use
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, ints, 0, bytes.Length);

Answer (score 9):

Now It's Simple like follows,

```
int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(bytesArray, Convert.ToInt32);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is:

```
Span<int> integerArray = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(byteArray.AsSpan());
```

source -> [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029829/2791333](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029526/efficiently-writing-an-int-array-to-file)

Comment: This is of course optimal from a performance point of view, but I don't think that was the questioner's intention.

You are reinterpreting the byte array as an integer span. I guess the questioner wanted to have an array/span where each byte is seen as an individual integer.

Comment: This is just a cast, so if you have bytes likes 1,2,3 it will convert them into some really big integer, which might not be what you want.