# Byte[] to float[] to Byte[]

Tags: c#, type-conversion

For some calculations I need to use Floats,
but I have an byte[] at my disposal so I first do:

```
Array.Copy(byteArray, floatArray, byteArray.Length);
```

That works great, I the do some calulations on the floats.but now I need to convert it back to an byteArray. I can't use the following code, it crashes, without giving an specific error message.

```
float[] DiffernetfloatArray= new float[ byteArray];  
Array.Copy(DiffernetfloatArray, byteArray, DiffernetfloatArray.Length);
```

First I thought it was the size that wasn't OK, but the float array that I'm using, I increased the size by 500 just for testing, still gave me same error

Does anyone know how I could fix this?
Preferably answers in C#

Comment: You should read this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896680/int-array-to-byte-array?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

its easier with linq:

```
var byteArray = floatArray.Select(f => Convert.ToByte(f)).ToArray();
var floatArray = byteArray.Select(b => (float)Convert.ToDouble(b)).ToArray();
```

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll` is much preferred.

Comment: i don't think so, you have to write more code becouse you haven't a converter to float, so you have to write a method to convert it

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way:

```
System.BitConverter.GetBytes(float)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

A byte can be converted to a float as it will fit within the type, but going the other way cannot be done with an implicit conversion - a float may be far too big to fit into a byte, therefore an `Array.Copy` will never work in this scenario.

Comment: @0A0D - A byte array and a float array.  Each value will be a one-to-one mapping, therefore one float will have to fit into one byte.

Comment: You can have a larger byte array.

Comment: You could, but Array.Copy with 3 arguments won't do that.