# c# error - Can not convert Array to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json, string

I am trying cast a Json data to byte array and then save it in SQL image field, code is below

```
public string Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
               imgPhoto1 = (byte[])item["Photo1"];
        }
 }
```

But getting error `Can not convert Array to byte array`

```
 byte[] imgPhoto1 = (byte[])item["Photo1"];
```

Values in field **item["Photo1"]** is look like below

```
 [255,216,255,224]
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What type is item["Photo1"]? Can it be cast to byte[]?

Comment: That is not a [mcve].

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `dynamic`... Not that it would solve this specific problem, but still.

Comment: I am not fan of dynamic so i would recommend using specified model. You can use `.Cast<byte>()` from `System.Linq` on yours `item["Photo 1"]`.

Comment: @Rakesh the question still doesn't explain what `item["Photo1"]` contains. It could be an `int[]` or `long[]`. It's definitely not a `byte[]`, which is why you get that exception

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896680/converting-an-int-to-byte-in-c-sharp

Comment: JSON is *text*, not binary data. You need to *deserialize* or parse that text to get the data.

Comment: @Rakesh I strongly suggest you edit the question, including the actual JSON **string**, and the code that lead to the error.

Comment: Also, what serializer is used? And what is data? That is, what *type* it is?

Comment: What is the value of `item["Photo1"].GetType()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your parameter `data` is `JToken`, then you need convert it to desired type.
Try to use:

```cs
var obj = item["Photo1"].ToObject<byte[]>();
```

And will be better explicit declare your parameter `data` as `JToken`.